# Error loading data from server: apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http-error: (curl error: 7)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor, mediawiki-visualeditor

Whenever I click on "Edit" on my mediawiki site that error always show, and I am unable to proceed to Visual editor, I suspect that my pathing is wrong in some URL.
Here is my configuration of parsoid in LocalSettings.php

```
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
        // URL to the Parsoid instance
        // Use port 8142 if you use the Debian package
        'url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
        // Parsoid "domain", see below (optional)
        'domain' => 'localhost',
        // Parsoid "prefix", see below (optional)
        'prefix' => 'localhost'
);
```

And here is my config.yaml

```
  mwApis:
    - # This is the only required parameter,
      # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.
      uri: 'http://192.168.195.166/mediawiki/w/api.php'
      # The "domain" is used for communication with Visual Editor
      # and RESTBase.  It defaults to the hostname portion of
      # the `uri` property below, but you can manually set it
      # to an arbitrary string.
      domain: 'localhost'  # optional
```

Answer (score -1):

you just have to remove the "w" from your path, and always keep the port of the parsoid api on (node ​​bin / serve.js)

mwApis:
    - # This is the only required parameter,
      # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.
      uri: 'http://192.168.195.166/mediawiki/api.php'
      # The "domain" is used for communication with Visual Editor
      # and RESTBase.  It defaults to the hostname portion of
      # the `uri` property below, but you can manually set it
      # to an arbitrary string.
      domain: 'localhost'  # optional